# Fixed element in CSS Grid, differences in Firefox, Chrome

Tags: html, css

I've noticed a strange difference in CSS grid elements between Firefox (57.0.1) and Chrome (65.0.3325.181).

If you **[look at this pen](https://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/yKdyRP)** in Firefox vs Chrome, you'll see that Firefox preserves the grid position of the child element. Other parameters (like width) are treated outside the flow of the document (text won't wrap within the width of the container column), but it's horizontal and vertical position are maintained.

Here's a sample:

```html
<main>
  <div id="left"><p>Left div, fixed position</p></div>
  <div id="right">
    <p>Right div, relative position, large block of text to scroll, etc.</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry...</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 10% auto 10%;
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 7px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#left {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display:block;
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1;
  align-self:center;  
  position:fixed;
}

#right {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  grid-row: 1 / 3 span;
  grid-column: 2;
  align-self: center;
}

#right p { font-size: 1.6rem; }
```

Is this documented behavior somewhere? Or, is it something that will be coming as standard in the future?